# Internet connection really slow on my Ubuntu 12.04 using D-Link DWA-510

Tags: 12.04, wireless, ralink

I installed Ubuntu today and I'm now dual booting Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04.

For some reason, the wireless is really slow on my Ubuntu. It works fine sometimes, but then gets really slow. I checked the connection on other laptops, ipads in my house and it works fine there.

For some reason, Ubuntu is slowing down my wireless. How should I go about debugging this?

Output of lspci -v

```
05:01.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT2561/RT61 rev B 802.11g    
Subsystem: D-Link System Inc DWA-510 Wireless G Desktop Adapter
Flags: bus master, slow devsel, latency 32, IRQ 19
Memory at ea100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: rt61pci
Kernel modules: rt61pci
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do:

```
echo "options rt61pci nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rt61pci.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv rt61pci
sudo modprobe -v rt61pci
```

It changes encryption from hardware to software and in many cases makes the connection faster and more stable.

Comment: And... what will this do to my system?